# Install conda library package (simple-salesforce) not working on Mojave (OS 10.14.4)

Tags: macos, python, anaconda

I am trying to install a library thru conda install to my Anaconda Navigator environment.

I am getting the following error:

```
[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/anaconda3/python.app/Contents/PkgInfo' -> '/anaconda3/python.app/Contents/PkgInfo.c~'
```

I found some suggested solution and already added Terminal & Anaconda Navigator to Full Disk Access in Settings, but didnt help.

I tried both suggested terminal statements:

To install this package with conda run one of the following:

```
conda install -c conda-forge simple-salesforce 
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 simple-salesforce
```

Both resulted in the same error. Also it identifies a lot of packages to be downgraded.

```
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: | 
Warning: 2 possible package resolutions (only showing differing packages):
  - conda-forge::llvmlite-0.26.0-py36h3fea490_1000, conda-forge::numba-0.41.0-py36h1702cab_1000, defaults::numpy-1.16.2-py36hacdab7b_0, defaults::numpy-base-1.16.2-py36h6575580_0
  - conda-forge::llvmlite-0.28.0-py36hf292337_0, conda-forge::numba-0.43.1-py36h6de7cb9_0, defaults::numpy-1.15.4-py36hacdab7b_0, defaults::numpy-base-1.15.4-py36h6575580done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - simple-salesforce


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  blinker            conda-forge/noarch::blinker-1.4-py_1
  boto3              conda-forge/noarch::boto3-1.9.134-py_0
  botocore           conda-forge/noarch::botocore-1.12.134-py_0
  bz2file            conda-forge/noarch::bz2file-0.98-py_0
  gensim             pkgs/main/osx-64::gensim-3.4.0-py36h1de35cc_0
  jmespath           conda-forge/noarch::jmespath-0.9.4-py_0
  matplotlib-base    conda-forge/osx-64::matplotlib-base-3.0.3-py36hf043ca5_0
  oauthlib           conda-forge/noarch::oauthlib-3.0.1-py_0
  pyjwt              conda-forge/noarch::pyjwt-1.7.1-py_0
  python-crfsuite    conda-forge/osx-64::python-crfsuite-0.9.6-py36h04f5b5a_1000
  requests-oauthlib  conda-forge/noarch::requests-oauthlib-1.2.0-py_0
  s3transfer         conda-forge/osx-64::s3transfer-0.2.0-py36_0
  simple-salesforce  conda-forge/osx-64::simple-salesforce-0.74.2-py36_0
  smart_open         conda-forge/noarch::smart_open-1.8.1-py_0
  sphinxcontrib-app~ conda-forge/noarch::sphinxcontrib-applehelp-1.0.1-py_0
  sphinxcontrib-dev~ conda-forge/noarch::sphinxcontrib-devhelp-1.0.1-py_0
  sphinxcontrib-htm~ conda-forge/noarch::sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp-1.0.2-py_0
  sphinxcontrib-jsm~ conda-forge/noarch::sphinxcontrib-jsmath-1.0.1-py_0
  sphinxcontrib-qth~ conda-forge/noarch::sphinxcontrib-qthelp-1.0.2-py_0
  sphinxcontrib-ser~ conda-forge/noarch::sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml-1.1.1-py_0
  twython            conda-forge/noarch::twython-3.7.0-py_0
  typed-ast          conda-forge/osx-64::typed-ast-1.3.4-py36h01d97ff_0

The following packages will be REMOVED:

  anaconda-2019.03-py37_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  anaconda-project   pkgs/main/osx-64::anaconda-project-0.~ --> conda-forge/noarch::anaconda-project-0.8.2-py_1
  appnope                   pkgs/main::appnope-0.1.0-py37_0 --> conda-forge::appnope-0.1.0-py36_1000
  asn1crypto            pkgs/main::asn1crypto-0.24.0-py37_0 --> conda-forge::asn1crypto-0.24.0-py36_1003
  babel                pkgs/main/osx-64::babel-2.6.0-py37_0 --> conda-forge/noarch::babel-2.6.0-py_1
  backports          pkgs/main/osx-64::backports-1.0-py37_1 --> conda-forge/noarch::backports-1.0-py_2
  backports.os         pkgs/main::backports.os-0.1.1-py37_0 --> conda-forge::backports.os-0.1.1-py36_1000
  backports.shutil_~ pkgs/main/osx-64::backports.shutil_ge~ --> conda-forge/noarch::backports.shutil_get_terminal_size-1.0.0-py_3
  beautifulsoup4     pkgs/main::beautifulsoup4-4.7.1-py37_1 --> conda-forge::beautifulsoup4-4.7.1-py36_1001
  bitarray           pkgs/main::bitarray-0.8.3-py37h1de35c~ --> conda-forge::bitarray-0.8.3-py36h1de35cc_1000
  bokeh                       pkgs/main::bokeh-1.0.4-py37_0 --> conda-forge::bokeh-1.1.0-py36_0
  bottleneck         pkgs/main::bottleneck-1.2.1-py37h1d22~ --> conda-forge::bottleneck-1.2.1-py36h917ab60_1001
  ca-certificates    pkgs/main::ca-certificates-2019.1.23-0 --> conda-forge::ca-certificates-2019.3.9-hecc5488_0
  cffi                pkgs/main::cffi-1.12.2-py37hb5b8e2f_1 --> conda-forge::cffi-1.12.3-py36hccf1714_0
  chardet                   pkgs/main::chardet-3.0.4-py37_1 --> conda-forge::chardet-3.0.4-py36_1003
  cloudpickle        pkgs/main/osx-64::cloudpickle-0.8.0-p~ --> conda-forge/noarch::cloudpickle-0.8.1-py_0
  conda-build          pkgs/main::conda-build-3.17.8-py37_0 --> conda-forge::conda-build-3.17.8-py36_1
  conda-verify         pkgs/main::conda-verify-3.1.1-py37_0 --> conda-forge::conda-verify-3.1.1-py36_1000
  contextlib2        pkgs/main/osx-64::contextlib2-0.5.5-p~ --> conda-forge/noarch::contextlib2-0.5.5-py_2
  cycler             pkgs/main/osx-64::cycler-0.10.0-py37_0 --> conda-forge/noarch::cycler-0.10.0-py_1
  cython             pkgs/main::cython-0.29.6-py37h0a44026~ --> conda-forge::cython-0.29.7-py36h6de7cb9_0
  cytoolz            pkgs/main::cytoolz-0.9.0.1-py37h1de35~ --> conda-forge::cytoolz-0.9.0.1-py36h1de35cc_1001
  dask                  pkgs/main/osx-64::dask-1.1.4-py37_1 --> conda-forge/noarch::dask-1.2.0-py_0
  dask-core          pkgs/main/osx-64::dask-core-1.1.4-py3~ --> conda-forge/noarch::dask-core-1.2.0-py_0
  distributed          pkgs/main::distributed-1.26.0-py37_1 --> conda-forge::distributed-1.27.0-py36_0
  docutils                  pkgs/main::docutils-0.14-py37_0 --> conda-forge::docutils-0.14-py36_1001
  entrypoints             pkgs/main::entrypoints-0.3-py37_0 --> conda-forge::entrypoints-0.3-py36_1000
  et_xmlfile             pkgs/main::et_xmlfile-1.0.1-py37_0 --> conda-forge::et_xmlfile-1.0.1-py36_1000
  fastcache          pkgs/main::fastcache-1.0.2-py37h1de35~ --> conda-forge::fastcache-1.0.2-py36h1de35cc_1001
  flask                pkgs/main/osx-64::flask-1.0.2-py37_1 --> conda-forge/noarch::flask-1.0.2-py_2
  future                    pkgs/main::future-0.17.1-py37_0 --> conda-forge::future-0.17.1-py36_1000
  gmpy2               pkgs/main::gmpy2-2.0.8-py37h6ef4df4_2 --> conda-forge::gmpy2-2.0.8-py36h3aece09_1002
  h5py                 pkgs/main::h5py-2.9.0-py37h3134771_0 --> conda-forge::h5py-2.9.0-nompi_py36h35dc34b_1102
  heapdict                 pkgs/main::heapdict-1.0.0-py37_2 --> conda-forge::heapdict-1.0.0-py36_1000
  idna                           pkgs/main::idna-2.8-py37_0 --> conda-forge::idna-2.8-py36_1000
  importlib_metadata pkgs/main::importlib_metadata-0.8-py3~ --> conda-forge::importlib_metadata-0.9-py36_0
  ipykernel          pkgs/main::ipykernel-5.1.0-py37h39e3c~ --> conda-forge::ipykernel-5.1.0-py36h24bf2e0_1002
  ipython_genutils   pkgs/main/osx-64::ipython_genutils-0.~ --> conda-forge/noarch::ipython_genutils-0.2.0-py_1
  isort                      pkgs/main::isort-4.3.16-py37_0 --> conda-forge::isort-4.3.17-py36_0
  jdcal                  pkgs/main/osx-64::jdcal-1.4-py37_0 --> conda-forge/noarch::jdcal-1.4-py_1
  jinja2               pkgs/main/osx-64::jinja2-2.10-py37_0 --> conda-forge/noarch::jinja2-2.10.1-py_0
  jupyter_client     pkgs/main/osx-64::jupyter_client-5.2.~ --> conda-forge/noarch::jupyter_client-5.2.4-py_3
  keyring                  pkgs/main::keyring-18.0.0-py37_0 --> conda-forge::keyring-19.0.1-py36_0
  kiwisolver         pkgs/main::kiwisolver-1.0.1-py37h0a44~ --> conda-forge::kiwisolver-1.0.1-py36h04f5b5a_1002
  lazy-object-proxy  pkgs/main::lazy-object-proxy-1.3.1-py~ --> conda-forge::lazy-object-proxy-1.3.1-py36h1de35cc_1000
  locket              pkgs/main/osx-64::locket-0.2.0-py37_1 --> conda-forge/noarch::locket-0.2.0-py_2
  lxml                 pkgs/main::lxml-4.3.2-py37hef8c89e_0 --> conda-forge::lxml-4.3.3-py36h08abf6f_0
  mistune            pkgs/main::mistune-0.8.4-py37h1de35cc~ --> conda-forge::mistune-0.8.4-py36h1de35cc_1000
  mkl_fft            pkgs/main::mkl_fft-1.0.10-py37h5e564d~ --> conda-forge::mkl_fft-1.0.12-py36h1de35cc_0
  mkl_random         pkgs/main::mkl_random-1.0.2-py37h27c9~ --> conda-forge::mkl_random-1.0.2-py36h1702cab_2
  nbformat           pkgs/main/osx-64::nbformat-4.4.0-py37~ --> conda-forge/noarch::nbformat-4.4.0-py_1
  networkx            pkgs/main/osx-64::networkx-2.2-py37_1 --> conda-forge/noarch::networkx-2.3-py_0
  nose                         pkgs/main::nose-1.3.7-py37_2 --> conda-forge::nose-1.3.7-py36_1002
  numexpr            pkgs/main::numexpr-2.6.9-py37h7413580~ --> conda-forge::numexpr-2.6.9-py36h1702cab_1000
  numpydoc           pkgs/main/osx-64::numpydoc-0.8.0-py37~ --> conda-forge/noarch::numpydoc-0.8.0-py_1
  openssl              pkgs/main::openssl-1.1.1b-h1de35cc_1 --> conda-forge::openssl-1.1.1b-h01d97ff_2
  parso                pkgs/main/osx-64::parso-0.3.4-py37_0 --> conda-forge/noarch::parso-0.4.0-py_0
  path.py            pkgs/main/osx-64::path.py-11.5.0-py37~ --> conda-forge/noarch::path.py-12.0.1-py_0
  pathlib2                 pkgs/main::pathlib2-2.3.3-py37_0 --> conda-forge::pathlib2-2.3.3-py36_1000
  pexpect                   pkgs/main::pexpect-4.6.0-py37_0 --> conda-forge::pexpect-4.7.0-py36_0
  pickleshare           pkgs/main::pickleshare-0.7.5-py37_0 --> conda-forge::pickleshare-0.7.5-py36_1000
  pillow                               5.4.1-py37hb68e598_0 --> 6.0.0-py36hb68e598_0
  ply                     pkgs/main/osx-64::ply-3.11-py37_0 --> conda-forge/noarch::ply-3.11-py_1
  ptyprocess         pkgs/main/osx-64::ptyprocess-0.6.0-py~ --> conda-forge/noarch::ptyprocess-0.6.0-py_1001
  pycosat            pkgs/main::pycosat-0.6.3-py37h1de35cc~ --> conda-forge::pycosat-0.6.3-py36h1de35cc_1001
  pycparser                pkgs/main::pycparser-2.19-py37_0 --> conda-forge::pycparser-2.19-py36_1
  pycrypto           pkgs/main::pycrypto-2.6.1-py37h1de35c~ --> conda-forge::pycrypto-2.6.1-py36h1de35cc_1002
  pyparsing          pkgs/main/osx-64::pyparsing-2.3.1-py3~ --> conda-forge/noarch::pyparsing-2.4.0-py_0
  pysocks                   pkgs/main::pysocks-1.6.8-py37_0 --> conda-forge::pysocks-1.6.8-py36_1002
  pytest                     pkgs/main::pytest-4.3.1-py37_0 --> conda-forge::pytest-4.4.1-py36_0
  python-libarchive~ pkgs/main::python-libarchive-c-2.8-py~ --> conda-forge::python-libarchive-c-2.8-py36_1004
  pytz                 pkgs/main/osx-64::pytz-2018.9-py37_0 --> conda-forge/noarch::pytz-2019.1-py_0
  pywavelets         pkgs/main::pywavelets-1.0.2-py37h1d22~ --> conda-forge::pywavelets-1.0.3-py36h1e5eb4f_1
  pyzmq              pkgs/main::pyzmq-18.0.0-py37h0a44026_0 --> conda-forge::pyzmq-18.0.1-py36h2d07e9b_1
  requests                pkgs/main::requests-2.21.0-py37_0 --> conda-forge::requests-2.21.0-py36_1000
  ruamel_yaml        pkgs/main::ruamel_yaml-0.15.46-py37h1~ --> conda-forge::ruamel_yaml-0.15.71-py36h1de35cc_1000
  scikit-image       pkgs/main::scikit-image-0.14.2-py37h0~ --> conda-forge::scikit-image-0.15.0-py36h6de7cb9_0
  setuptools            pkgs/main::setuptools-40.8.0-py37_0 --> conda-forge::setuptools-41.0.0-py36_0
  singledispatch     pkgs/main::singledispatch-3.4.0.3-py3~ --> conda-forge::singledispatch-3.4.0.3-py36_1000
  sip                  pkgs/main::sip-4.19.8-py37h0a44026_0 --> conda-forge::sip-4.19.8-py36h0a44026_1000
  six                          pkgs/main::six-1.12.0-py37_0 --> conda-forge::six-1.12.0-py36_1000
  snowballstemmer    pkgs/main/osx-64::snowballstemmer-1.2~ --> conda-forge/noarch::snowballstemmer-1.2.1-py_1
  soupsieve                 pkgs/main::soupsieve-1.8-py37_0 --> conda-forge::soupsieve-1.9.1-py36_0
  sphinx              pkgs/main/osx-64::sphinx-1.8.5-py37_0 --> conda-forge/noarch::sphinx-2.0.1-py_0
  spyder-kernels     pkgs/main::spyder-kernels-0.4.2-py37_0 --> conda-forge::spyder-kernels-0.4.4-py36_0
  sqlalchemy         pkgs/main::sqlalchemy-1.3.1-py37h1de3~ --> conda-forge::sqlalchemy-1.3.3-py36h01d97ff_0
  statsmodels        pkgs/main::statsmodels-0.9.0-py37h1d2~ --> conda-forge::statsmodels-0.9.0-py36h917ab60_1000
  sympy                         pkgs/main::sympy-1.3-py37_0 --> conda-forge::sympy-1.4-py36_0
  tblib                pkgs/main/osx-64::tblib-1.3.2-py37_0 --> conda-forge/noarch::tblib-1.3.2-py_1
  terminado               pkgs/main::terminado-0.8.1-py37_1 --> conda-forge::terminado-0.8.2-py36_0
  testpath           pkgs/main/osx-64::testpath-0.4.2-py37~ --> conda-forge/noarch::testpath-0.4.2-py_1001
  toolz                pkgs/main/osx-64::toolz-0.9.0-py37_0 --> conda-forge/noarch::toolz-0.9.0-py_1
  traitlets               pkgs/main::traitlets-4.3.2-py37_0 --> conda-forge::traitlets-4.3.2-py36_1000
  unicodecsv         pkgs/main/osx-64::unicodecsv-0.14.1-p~ --> conda-forge/noarch::unicodecsv-0.14.1-py_1
  urllib3                  pkgs/main::urllib3-1.24.1-py37_0 --> conda-forge::urllib3-1.24.2-py36_0
  wcwidth            pkgs/main/osx-64::wcwidth-0.1.7-py37_0 --> conda-forge/noarch::wcwidth-0.1.7-py_1
  werkzeug           pkgs/main/osx-64::werkzeug-0.14.1-py3~ --> conda-forge/noarch::werkzeug-0.15.2-py_0
  widgetsnbextension pkgs/main::widgetsnbextension-3.4.2-p~ --> conda-forge::widgetsnbextension-3.4.2-py36_1000
  wurlitzer               pkgs/main::wurlitzer-1.0.2-py37_0 --> conda-forge::wurlitzer-1.0.2-py36_1000
  xlsxwriter         pkgs/main/osx-64::xlsxwriter-1.1.5-py~ --> conda-forge/noarch::xlsxwriter-1.1.7-py_0
  xlwings                  pkgs/main::xlwings-0.15.4-py37_0 --> conda-forge::xlwings-0.15.5-py36_0
  xlwt                  pkgs/main/osx-64::xlwt-1.3.0-py37_0 --> conda-forge/noarch::xlwt-1.3.0-py_1

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  alabaster          pkgs/main/osx-64::alabaster-0.7.12-py~ --> conda-forge/noarch::alabaster-0.7.12-py_0
  anaconda-client    pkgs/main/osx-64::anaconda-client-1.7~ --> conda-forge/noarch::anaconda-client-1.7.2-py_0
  appscript          pkgs/main::appscript-1.1.0-py37h1de35~ --> conda-forge::appscript-1.1.0-py36h01d97ff_0
  astroid                   pkgs/main::astroid-2.2.5-py37_0 --> conda-forge::astroid-2.2.5-py36_0
  astropy            pkgs/main::astropy-3.1.2-py37h1de35cc~ --> conda-forge::astropy-3.1.2-py36h1de35cc_0
  atomicwrites       pkgs/main/osx-64::atomicwrites-1.3.0-~ --> conda-forge/noarch::atomicwrites-1.3.0-py_0
  attrs               pkgs/main/osx-64::attrs-19.1.0-py37_1 --> conda-forge/noarch::attrs-19.1.0-py_0
  backcall           pkgs/main/osx-64::backcall-0.1.0-py37~ --> conda-forge/noarch::backcall-0.1.0-py_0
  bkcharts                   pkgs/main::bkcharts-0.2-py37_0 --> conda-forge::bkcharts-0.2-py36_0
  bleach              pkgs/main/osx-64::bleach-3.1.0-py37_0 --> conda-forge/noarch::bleach-3.1.0-py_0
  boto                 pkgs/main/osx-64::boto-2.49.0-py37_0 --> conda-forge/noarch::boto-2.49.0-py_0
  certifi                pkgs/main::certifi-2019.3.9-py37_0 --> conda-forge::certifi-2019.3.9-py36_0
  click                  pkgs/main/osx-64::click-7.0-py37_0 --> conda-forge/noarch::click-7.0-py_0
  clyent              pkgs/main/osx-64::clyent-1.2.2-py37_1 --> conda-forge/noarch::clyent-1.2.2-py_1
  colorama           pkgs/main/osx-64::colorama-0.4.1-py37~ --> conda-forge/noarch::colorama-0.4.1-py_0
  cryptography       pkgs/main::cryptography-2.6.1-py37ha1~ --> conda-forge::cryptography-2.6.1-py36h212c5bf_0
  decorator          pkgs/main/osx-64::decorator-4.4.0-py3~ --> conda-forge/noarch::decorator-4.4.0-py_0
  defusedxml         pkgs/main/osx-64::defusedxml-0.5.0-py~ --> conda-forge/noarch::defusedxml-0.5.0-py_1
  filelock           pkgs/main/osx-64::filelock-3.0.10-py3~ --> conda-forge/noarch::filelock-3.0.10-py_0
  gevent             pkgs/main::gevent-1.4.0-py37h1de35cc_0 --> conda-forge::gevent-1.3.7-py36h470a237_0
  glob2                  pkgs/main/osx-64::glob2-0.6-py37_1 --> conda-forge/noarch::glob2-0.6-py_0
  greenlet           pkgs/main::greenlet-0.4.15-py37h1de35~ --> conda-forge::greenlet-0.4.13-py36_0
  html5lib           pkgs/main/osx-64::html5lib-1.0.1-py37~ --> conda-forge/noarch::html5lib-1.0.1-py_0
  imageio                   pkgs/main::imageio-2.5.0-py37_0 --> conda-forge::imageio-2.5.0-py36_0
  imagesize          pkgs/main/osx-64::imagesize-1.1.0-py3~ --> conda-forge/noarch::imagesize-1.1.0-py_0
  ipython            pkgs/main::ipython-7.4.0-py37h39e3cac~ --> conda-forge::ipython-7.4.0-py36h24bf2e0_0
  ipywidgets         pkgs/main/osx-64::ipywidgets-7.4.2-py~ --> conda-forge/noarch::ipywidgets-7.4.2-py_0
  itsdangerous       pkgs/main/osx-64::itsdangerous-1.1.0-~ --> conda-forge/noarch::itsdangerous-1.1.0-py_0
  jedi                        pkgs/main::jedi-0.13.3-py37_0 --> conda-forge::jedi-0.13.3-py36_0
  jsonschema             pkgs/main::jsonschema-3.0.1-py37_0 --> conda-forge::jsonschema-3.0.1-py36_0
  jupyter            pkgs/main/osx-64::jupyter-1.0.0-py37_7 --> conda-forge/noarch::jupyter-1.0.0-py_2
  jupyter_console    pkgs/main/osx-64::jupyter_console-6.0~ --> conda-forge/noarch::jupyter_console-6.0.0-py_0
  jupyter_core       pkgs/main/osx-64::jupyter_core-4.4.0-~ --> conda-forge/noarch::jupyter_core-4.4.0-py_0
  jupyterlab         pkgs/main::jupyterlab-0.35.4-py37hf63~ --> conda-forge::jupyterlab-0.35.4-py36_0
  jupyterlab_server  pkgs/main/osx-64::jupyterlab_server-0~ --> conda-forge/noarch::jupyterlab_server-0.2.0-py_0
  llvmlite           pkgs/main::llvmlite-0.28.0-py37h8c7ce~ --> conda-forge::llvmlite-0.26.0-py36h3fea490_1000
  markupsafe         pkgs/main::markupsafe-1.1.1-py37h1de3~ --> conda-forge::markupsafe-1.1.1-py36h1de35cc_0
  matplotlib         pkgs/main::matplotlib-3.0.3-py37h54f8~ --> conda-forge::matplotlib-3.0.3-py36_0
  mccabe              pkgs/main/osx-64::mccabe-0.6.1-py37_1 --> conda-forge/noarch::mccabe-0.6.1-py_1
  more-itertools     pkgs/main::more-itertools-6.0.0-py37_0 --> conda-forge::more-itertools-4.3.0-py36_1000
  mpmath              pkgs/main/osx-64::mpmath-1.1.0-py37_0 --> conda-forge/noarch::mpmath-1.1.0-py_0
  msgpack-python     pkgs/main::msgpack-python-0.6.1-py37h~ --> conda-forge::msgpack-python-0.6.1-py36h04f5b5a_0
  multipledispatch   pkgs/main/osx-64::multipledispatch-0.~ --> conda-forge/noarch::multipledispatch-0.6.0-py_0
  nbconvert          pkgs/main/osx-64::nbconvert-5.4.1-py3~ --> conda-forge/noarch::nbconvert-5.4.1-py_2
  nltk                    pkgs/main/osx-64::nltk-3.4-py37_1 --> conda-forge/noarch::nltk-3.2.5-py_0
  notebook                 pkgs/main::notebook-5.7.8-py37_0 --> conda-forge::notebook-5.7.8-py36_0
  numba              pkgs/main::numba-0.43.1-py37h6440ff4_0 --> conda-forge::numba-0.41.0-py36h1702cab_1000
  olefile             pkgs/main/osx-64::olefile-0.46-py37_0 --> conda-forge/noarch::olefile-0.46-py_0
  openpyxl           pkgs/main/osx-64::openpyxl-2.6.1-py37~ --> conda-forge/noarch::openpyxl-2.6.1-py_0
  packaging          pkgs/main/osx-64::packaging-19.0-py37~ --> conda-forge/noarch::packaging-19.0-py_0
  pandas             pkgs/main::pandas-0.24.2-py37h0a44026~ --> conda-forge::pandas-0.24.2-py36h0a44026_0
  pandocfilters      pkgs/main/osx-64::pandocfilters-1.4.2~ --> conda-forge/noarch::pandocfilters-1.4.2-py_1
  partd               pkgs/main/osx-64::partd-0.3.10-py37_1 --> conda-forge/noarch::partd-0.3.9-py_0
  patsy                pkgs/main/osx-64::patsy-0.5.1-py37_0 --> conda-forge/noarch::patsy-0.5.1-py_0
  pep8                  pkgs/main/osx-64::pep8-1.7.1-py37_0 --> conda-forge/noarch::pep8-1.7.1-py_0
  pip                          pkgs/main::pip-19.0.3-py37_0 --> conda-forge::pip-19.0.3-py36_0
  pkginfo            pkgs/main/osx-64::pkginfo-1.5.0.1-py3~ --> conda-forge/noarch::pkginfo-1.5.0.1-py_0
  pluggy              pkgs/main/osx-64::pluggy-0.9.0-py37_0 --> conda-forge/noarch::pluggy-0.9.0-py_0
  prometheus_client  pkgs/main/osx-64::prometheus_client-0~ --> conda-forge/noarch::prometheus_client-0.6.0-py_0
  prompt_toolkit     pkgs/main/osx-64::prompt_toolkit-2.0.~ --> conda-forge/noarch::prompt_toolkit-2.0.9-py_0
  psutil             pkgs/main::psutil-5.6.1-py37h1de35cc_0 --> conda-forge::psutil-5.6.1-py36h1de35cc_0
  py                      pkgs/main/osx-64::py-1.8.0-py37_0 --> conda-forge/noarch::py-1.8.0-py_0
  pycodestyle        pkgs/main/osx-64::pycodestyle-2.5.0-p~ --> conda-forge/noarch::pycodestyle-2.5.0-py_0
  pyflakes           pkgs/main/osx-64::pyflakes-2.1.1-py37~ --> conda-forge/noarch::pyflakes-2.1.1-py_0
  pygments           pkgs/main/osx-64::pygments-2.3.1-py37~ --> conda-forge/noarch::pygments-2.3.1-py_0
  pylint                     pkgs/main::pylint-2.3.1-py37_0 --> conda-forge::pylint-2.3.1-py36_0
  pyodbc             pkgs/main::pyodbc-4.0.26-py37h0a44026~ --> conda-forge::pyodbc-4.0.26-py36h0a44026_0
  pyopenssl              pkgs/main::pyopenssl-19.0.0-py37_0 --> conda-forge::pyopenssl-19.0.0-py36_0
  pyrsistent         pkgs/main::pyrsistent-0.14.11-py37h1d~ --> conda-forge::pyrsistent-0.14.11-py36h1de35cc_0
  pytables           pkgs/main::pytables-3.5.1-py37h5bccee~ --> conda-forge::pytables-3.4.4-py36h0af8b44_1004
  pytest-arraydiff   pkgs/main/osx-64::pytest-arraydiff-0.~ --> conda-forge/noarch::pytest-arraydiff-0.3-py_0
  pytest-astropy     pkgs/main/osx-64::pytest-astropy-0.5.~ --> conda-forge/noarch::pytest-astropy-0.5.0-py_0
  pytest-doctestplus pkgs/main/osx-64::pytest-doctestplus-~ --> conda-forge/noarch::pytest-doctestplus-0.3.0-py_0
  pytest-openfiles   pkgs/main/osx-64::pytest-openfiles-0.~ --> conda-forge/noarch::pytest-openfiles-0.3.1-py_0
  pytest-remotedata  pkgs/main/osx-64::pytest-remotedata-0~ --> conda-forge/noarch::pytest-remotedata-0.3.1-py_0
  python-dateutil    pkgs/main/osx-64::python-dateutil-2.8~ --> conda-forge/noarch::python-dateutil-2.8.0-py_0
  python.app                 pkgs/main::python.app-2-py37_9 --> conda-forge::python.app-1.2-py36h1de35cc_1200
  pyyaml               pkgs/main::pyyaml-5.1-py37h1de35cc_0 --> conda-forge::pyyaml-5.1-py36h1de35cc_0
  qtawesome          pkgs/main/osx-64::qtawesome-0.5.7-py3~ --> conda-forge/noarch::qtawesome-0.5.7-pyh8a2030e_0
  qtconsole          pkgs/main/osx-64::qtconsole-4.4.3-py3~ --> conda-forge/noarch::qtconsole-4.4.3-py_0
  qtpy                  pkgs/main/osx-64::qtpy-1.7.0-py37_1 --> conda-forge/noarch::qtpy-1.7.0-pyh8a2030e_0
  rope                 pkgs/main/osx-64::rope-0.12.0-py37_0 --> conda-forge/noarch::rope-0.10.7-py_1
  seaborn            pkgs/main/osx-64::seaborn-0.9.0-py37_0 --> conda-forge/noarch::seaborn-0.9.0-py_0
  send2trash         pkgs/main/osx-64::send2trash-1.5.0-py~ --> conda-forge/noarch::send2trash-1.5.0-py_0
  simplegeneric      pkgs/main/osx-64::simplegeneric-0.8.1~ --> conda-forge/noarch::simplegeneric-0.8.1-py_1
  sortedcollections  pkgs/main/osx-64::sortedcollections-1~ --> conda-forge/noarch::sortedcollections-1.1.2-py_0
  sortedcontainers   pkgs/main/osx-64::sortedcontainers-2.~ --> conda-forge/noarch::sortedcontainers-2.1.0-py_0
  sphinxcontrib-web~ pkgs/main/osx-64::sphinxcontrib-websu~ --> conda-forge/noarch::sphinxcontrib-websupport-1.1.0-py_1
  spyder                     pkgs/main::spyder-3.3.3-py37_0 --> conda-forge::spyder-3.3.1-py36_2
  tornado            pkgs/main::tornado-6.0.2-py37h1de35cc~ --> conda-forge::tornado-6.0.2-py36h01d97ff_0
  tqdm                 pkgs/main/osx-64::tqdm-4.31.1-py37_1 --> conda-forge/noarch::tqdm-4.31.1-py_0
  webencodings       pkgs/main/osx-64::webencodings-0.5.1-~ --> conda-forge/noarch::webencodings-0.5.1-py_1
  wheel                      pkgs/main::wheel-0.33.1-py37_0 --> conda-forge::wheel-0.33.1-py36_0
  wrapt              pkgs/main::wrapt-1.11.1-py37h1de35cc_0 --> conda-forge::wrapt-1.11.1-py36h1de35cc_0
  xlrd                  pkgs/main/osx-64::xlrd-1.2.0-py37_0 --> conda-forge/noarch::xlrd-1.2.0-py_0
  zict                  pkgs/main/osx-64::zict-0.1.4-py37_0 --> conda-forge/noarch::zict-0.1.4-py_0
  zipp                  pkgs/main/osx-64::zipp-0.3.3-py37_1 --> conda-forge/noarch::zipp-0.3.3-py_0

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  _ipyw_jlab_nb_ext~                           0.1.0-py37_0 --> 0.1.0-py36_0
  anaconda-navigator                           1.9.7-py37_0 --> 1.9.7-py36_0
  conda                                       4.6.14-py37_0 --> 4.6.14-py36_0
  mkl-service                          1.1.2-py37hfbe908c_5 --> 1.1.2-py36hfbe908c_5
  navigator-updater                            0.2.1-py37_0 --> 0.2.1-py36_0
  numpy                               1.16.2-py37hacdab7b_0 --> 1.16.2-py36hacdab7b_0
  numpy-base                          1.16.2-py37h6575580_0 --> 1.16.2-py36h6575580_0
  py-lief                              0.9.0-py37h1413db1_2 --> 0.9.0-py36h1413db1_2
  pycurl                            7.43.0.2-py37ha12b0ac_0 --> 7.43.0.2-py36ha12b0ac_0
  pyqt                                 5.9.2-py37h655552a_2 --> 5.9.2-py36h655552a_2
  python                                   3.7.3-h359304d_0 --> 3.6.8-haf84260_0
  scikit-learn                        0.20.3-py37h27c97d8_0 --> 0.20.3-py36h27c97d8_0
  scipy                                1.2.1-py37h1410ff5_0 --> 1.2.1-py36h1410ff5_0
  sphinxcontrib                                  1.0-py37_1 --> 1.0-py36_1


Proceed ([y]/n)? 
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(568): An error occurred while uninstalling package 'defaults::python.app-2-py37_9'.
PermissionError(1, 'Operation not permitted')
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done


Conda update -all works fine:
(base) sdfsd:~ user$ conda update --all
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```